# How are The Doctor and his TARDIS connected?

Tags: doctor-who, tardis

I was listening to some Chameleon Circuit, and I noticed this line:

> I'm linked to the Doctor symbiotically
>   
> Got his imprint on my Briode Nebuliser

And I looked it up, this is what `tardis.wikia` had to say about the 'Briode Nebuliser'

> The briode nebuliser was a component of the Kartz-Reimer module. The Sixth Doctor sabotaged the module by paring the briode nebuliser's interface. He left a thin membrane of the interface so it would only work once, which ensured the survival of Peri Brown when she was forced to take the module on a test journey. As a result of the Doctor's sabotage, the module exploded on its second use, killing its occupant Chessene of the Franzine Grig.

The [Kartz-Reimer](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Kartz-Reimer_module) module it appears is a nascent time travel device. I don't see why the Tardis would have one. *Are Chameleon Circuit making a round about reference to the [Rassilon Imprimatur](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Rassilon_Imprimatur)?*

I can't tell.

---

Is the doctor somehow specially linked to his Type-40 TARDIS? More so than any other Time Lord was? If so how is the Briode Nebuliser linked to this?

Comment: There is a episode where the tardis is placed in a human and "she" says she picked him to escape Gallifrey (rather than the other way around)

Comment: There's the whole clicky-finger thing that allegedly only the Doctor can do with only his TARDIS, that never got an explanation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each Time Lord is symbiotically connected to their TARDIS, because Time Lords have symbiotic Nuclei (Including the Rassilon Imprimatur) which connect them to their TARDIS. As far as I can tell, it has nothing to do with a Briode Nebuliser. I was just listening to the song as well! The Doctor is not specially connected to his Type-40 TARDIS, except for it having "stolen" him (The Doctor's Wife), he's just connected like any other Time Lord.

Answer (score 2):

I probably think the TARDIS's sentience is rather connected to the Doctor, as we can see in "The Doctor's Wife". I think that over the time they have spent together, they have developed some sort of psychic link. And the Doctor might not be able to hear the TARDIS all the time, but the TARDIS can always hear the Doctor.